# Get Range of dates from an array

Tags: php

I'm having the following array of dates :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2016-02-01
    [1] => 2016-02-02
    [2] => 2016-02-03
    [3] => 2016-02-04
    [4] => 2016-02-05
    [5] => 2016-02-06
    [6] => 2016-02-07
    [7] => 2016-02-08
    [8] => 2016-02-09
    [9] => 2016-02-13
    [10] => 2016-02-14
    [11] => 2016-02-15
    [12] => 2016-03-13
    [13] => 2016-03-14
    [14] => 2016-03-15
    [15] => 2016-03-16
    [16] => 2016-03-17
    [17] => 2016-03-18
    [18] => 2016-03-19
    [19] => 2016-04-19
    [20] => 2016-04-20
    [21] => 2016-04-21
    [22] => 2016-04-22
)
```

How can i get the array dates that form a range. Like

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2016-02-01
    [1] => 2016-02-02
    [2] => 2016-02-03
    [3] => 2016-02-04
    [4] => 2016-02-05
    [5] => 2016-02-06
    [6] => 2016-02-07
    [7] => 2016-02-08
    [8] => 2016-02-09
)

Array
(
    [0] => 2016-02-13
    [1] => 2016-02-14
    [2] => 2016-02-15
)

Array
(
    [0] => 2016-03-13
    [1] => 2016-03-14
    [2] => 2016-03-15
    [3] => 2016-03-16
    [4] => 2016-03-17
    [5] => 2016-03-18
    [6] => 2016-03-19
)
```

The dates in the main array I listed can be of any order. The example I provided all the date ranges can be identifiable. But the raay is dynamic and can have date in random order. All I want to have date ranges out if that array. I'm getting mad of thinking. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: for the random order:http://php.net/manual/de/function.sort.php

Comment: @Franz Gleichmann but how can I get the dates ranges as array out of this array

Comment: First of all you have to much aware with PHP date functions. If you are, you are very easily do this stuff.

Comment: @KinjalMistry please suggest some ideas. I'm out of ideas here

Comment: how about you iterate the sorted array and check whether or not the new date is the day following the previous date....?

Comment: @Pranab Sorry for delay in reply. But Please check answer I just wrote down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the following code. Please try this.

```
    $array = Array(0 => '2016-02-01',
    1 => '2016-02-02',
    2 => '2016-03-19',
    3 => '2016-02-04',
    4 => '2016-02-05',
    5 => '2016-03-18',
    6 => '2016-02-07',
    7 => '2016-02-08',
    8 => '2016-02-09',
    9 => '2016-02-13',
    10 => '2016-02-14',
    11 => '2016-02-15',
    12 => '2016-03-13',
    13 => '2016-03-14',
    14 => '2016-03-15',
    15 => '2016-03-16',
    16 => '2016-03-17',
    17 => '2016-02-06',
    18 => '2016-02-03',
    19 => '2016-04-19',
    20 => '2016-04-20',
    21 => '2016-04-21',
    22 => '2016-04-22');

//echo "<pre>";print_r($array);
sort($array);

$newDateArray = array();
$i = 0;
$arrayCount = count($array);
foreach($array as $key=>$val) {
    //echo $key;
    if(isset($array[$key+1])) {
        $date1 = $val;
        $date2 = $array[$key+1];
        $newDateArray[$i][] = $date1;
        $datetime1 = date_create($date1);
        $datetime2 = date_create($date2);
        $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);

        if($interval->days > 1) {
            $i++;
        }
    }
    else if($arrayCount == ($key+1)) {
        $newDateArray[$i][] = $date2;
    }
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($newDateArray);exit;
```

your result would be as follows.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2016-02-01
            [1] => 2016-02-02
            [2] => 2016-02-03
            [3] => 2016-02-04
            [4] => 2016-02-05
            [5] => 2016-02-06
            [6] => 2016-02-07
            [7] => 2016-02-08
            [8] => 2016-02-09
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2016-02-13
            [1] => 2016-02-14
            [2] => 2016-02-15
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2016-03-13
            [1] => 2016-03-14
            [2] => 2016-03-15
            [3] => 2016-03-16
            [4] => 2016-03-17
            [5] => 2016-03-18
            [6] => 2016-03-19
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2016-04-19
            [1] => 2016-04-20
            [2] => 2016-04-21
            [3] => 2016-04-22
        )

)
```

Now you can easily split your array. and get the result what you exactly want. 
Have a Great Day!!!... Fill free to ask more your doubts...

Comment: @Pranab It's my pleasure.